# Odd navigation bar appearing in app being prepared for iOS7

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios7

I'm updating an old app that uses a split view for iOS7 and I've got an issue with an odd navigation bar appearing. I can't figure out where it's coming from for the life of me!! I want navigation bars so I can add bar button items, but I want them to be transparent as the split view background image is providing the bar effect.

I've tried making the navigation bar transparent in the master and detail VCs, and can't make this go away.

[image]

[image]

To help diagnose where it's coming from, I added this line of code to the app delegate and got the result below, which has me even more confused.

```
navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

[image]

[image]

If I run the same code in the simulator, the bar is still there, but it's bright purple!

[image]

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: I think you are using custom tool bar right?

Comment: simulator dosen't show proper background so test on device.

Comment: Yes I'm adding a custom toolbar as a bar button item.

Comment: i'm also facing the same issue some please help

Comment: I've come back to this app and still have this issue. Any ideas from anyone??

Answer (score 1):

**To make navigation bar transparent.**

```
navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: No luck. I even added these lines to all the VCs because I wasn't sure which one was presenting it, and it's still there!